# convert RAF files in imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

I'm trying to convert .RAF files to .png using imagemagick. When I invoke the command:

```
convert In.RAF Out.png
```

I get an error:

```
convert-im6.q16: delegate failed `'ufraw-batch' --silent --create-id=also --out-type=png --out-depth=16 --output='%u.png' '%i'' @ error/delegate.c/InvokeDelegate/1966.
convert-im6.q16: unable to open image `/tmp/magick-ejQzPVVSt94Dqk7SyrW5IgXBb7ujqXKS.ppm': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2924.
convert-im6.q16: no images defined `Out.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3229.
```

I can't make much sense out of this. Can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

***cough***  ***cough***  its dependency issue (`ufraw-batch`).

Imagemagick uses `ufraw-batch` in behind the scenes to convert raw files, but for whatever reason its missing.

so install it

```bsh
sudo apt install ufraw-batch
```

then

```bsh
convert In.RAF Out.png
```

tip: for multiple files use

```bsh
mogrify -format png *.RAF
```

Comment: Aah shows that I'm not quite fluent in error language :P Unfortunately it seems that ufraw is unmaintained and removed from repos. There is a fork called nUfraw that I haven't tested yet and I don't see high hopes of it being maintained. There is also dcraw that can do similar things. I'm guessing imagemagick will sort it out in a few months.

Comment: Its not your fault at all, usually when a dependency is not found, it should print something like 'xxx not found' but instead it showed failed and that's a bad practice .